# NuGet.Server crash on startup

Tags: iis, nuget, nuget-server

I setup [Nuget.Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server#:%7E:text=%20NuGet.Server%20%201%20Create%20and%20deploy%20an,removes%20a%20package%20from%20the%20repository...%20More%20) based on Visual Studio Project and Nuget.Server Package, and publish it to our IIS on Windows Server 2019.

In Server, We can open the Website at http://ServerName:Port and everything is ok. but when we open this url from our clients, we got error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Therefore, we decide to enable debug on NugetServer App, and this is the full error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    <% if (Request.IsLocal || ServiceResolver.Current.Resolve<NuGet.Server.Core.Infrastructure.ISettingsProvider>().GetBoolSetting("allowRemoteCacheManagement", false)) { %>

    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

   NuGet.Server.ServiceResolverExtensions.Resolve(IServiceResolver resolver) +50
   ASP.default_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in D:\WebApps\AryaVtd-NugetServer\Default.aspx:37
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +275
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +39
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4238
```

Server info: Windows Serve 2019, IIS, folder has security access enable for IIS_IUSER, Firewall is off for testing. Anonymous user is Enable on IIS and Impersonate is true.

Client info: Windows 10, Microsoft Edge, and user is domain user.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please try the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42449340/14162739) and you'd better to publish the application again. If it still reports the same error, it is necessary to use debugdiag to troubleshoot the detailed error.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but its different issue, we have issue on loading the default page. the default page loaded successfully on local server but not work on clients of network.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (same symptoms and same exception). It appeared that the cause was that I created a VB ASP.NET project instead of the C# one by mistake.
I don't think it's still actual for the question author, but I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, but its not my mistake.